# EU Settlement Scheme for Surinder Singh applicants

Tags: eu-citizens, surinder-singh, eu-settlement-scheme

We arrived in the UK on 21/12/17 after completing the Surinder Singh process in Spain. My wife received her UK Residence Card ( EU Family Member ) on 1/8/18.

I'm now reading that the EU settlement scheme, fully open from 31/3/19, is not  actually fully open for Surinder Singh cases. Furthermore, the simplified process will not be available for such applications and a long paper process ( not finalised to date) will be required. This information was received from Your Europe. I would be grateful clarification.

On a second, but related point. My wife has a son of 18, Argentinian national. He did not live with us in Spain but now wants to move permanently from Argentina to live here in the UK. Can he become part of the EU Settlement claim? He is here on a 6 month stay at present, Argentina being a non-visa national country.

Comment: Apologies!!!  Having looked again on Gov.UK, I see that Surinder Singh applications cannot be made online, paper applications are needed and I suspect will be just a re-run of the 100 page initial application.

Comment: If anyone can advise on the second point about my wife's son I'd be grateful.

Comment: Is your wife’s son dependent on her?

Comment: In the sense that he would have no job/no money if he stayed here then yes. The classification of a child seems to be 21 for the EU settlement scheme but as he wasn't with us in Spain as part of our Surinder Singh process, I was thinking he would not be in the qualified category.

Comment: I meant dependent on her in his normal place of residence, presumably Argentina since you mention that he didn’t live with you in Spain.

Comment: When we were in Spain, he stayed in Argentina with his grandmother and uncle and attended school. He finished school at 18, remained in Argentina and without a job. His mother and other family members supported him. My question really is whether he can be part of any future claim for settlement in the UK once my wife gets pre-settled status? My thinking is that he can't because he wasn't with us in Spain and as S9 of the 2016 Immigration rules (EU) apply he is precluded.